# How do you become a toad in Talisman?

Tags: talisman

I played the board game Talisman the other night and in the rulebook there was mention of what happens when you become a toad, but no indication of how that occurs.  I assumed that it was an effect from an event or dice roll (which it is in some cases), but a couple of the others had played where rolling a 1 multiple times during movement turned you into a toad.  We played for several hours (not getting very far) and did not turn to a toad even once, which does not seem correct even if limited to event cards or encounters.

EDIT:
The others who played before became toads more often, but am not sure if that was a house rule or an older edition rule.  Whether via events or encounters I would expect it to have happened at least once over several hours. We also ended up with several Place cards occupying the draw-a-card spaces

So, is there something missing from the rulebook, or has 4th edition changed to 'encourage' more PvP?

Comment: The [Enchantress](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Enchantress) in the Village (one of the corner squares) is a pretty common way to turn into a Toad, with a 1 in 6 chance if you visit her.

Answer (score 4):

It is hidden in the encounter section of [the rules](https://www.heidelbaer.de/documents/Talisman_Rules_eng.pdf):

> Other times the encounters are hostile
>   and attack the character, or even turn him into a slimy Toad!

You will remain a toad for three turns, unless:

> If a character is already a Toad and is turned into a Toad
>   again (for example, as a result of the [Random Spell](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Random)), the character
>   remains a Toad for three more turns starting from the
>   second transformation.

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty in the rules on [what happens when you turn into a toad](https://nomadgames.co.uk/talisman-digital-edition-manual-uk/#toads), but you have to look at specific encounters to see when it happens. Here are a few:

**1. Adventure cards** - The *[Witch](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Witch)* Stranger will turn you into a toad for three turns if you roll a 1. While this is the only adventure card in the base pack that will do this, there may be others in expansions.

**2. Spells** - The *[Random](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Random)* Spell will turn the character it is cast on into a toad for three turns if they roll a 1. There are 2 'Random' Spell cards in the base pack, but other spells may do this in expansions.

**3. Board Space Encounters** - One of the options at the *[City](http://www.talismanwiki.com/City_(Base_Game_Board))* board space is an encounter with an Enchantress who, just like the *Witch* Stranger can turn you into a toad for 3 turns.

Generally, there seem to be the highest number of ways to become a toad in the [Woodland expansion](https://nomadgames.co.uk/talisman-digital-edition-manual-uk/#woodland).